# Javascript + printing values from select box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a select box call 'ToLB' which takes in value items from another select box. I need to extract those selected values from 'ToLB' and print it on a label, this is how I do it but apparently it's not working as in no error message but nothing was printed to the label, please kindly advice, thanks! :

**The Select box:**

```
<select multiple size="8" name="ToLB" style="width: 135px" onblur="javascript:dropValue6(this)">
</select>
```

**The label:**

```
QMType: <asp:Label ID="destinationQualMemType" runat="server" ></asp:Label >
```

**Javascript function:**

```
function dropValue6(source) {
    while (source.selectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if (source.selectedIndex != 0) arSelected.push(source.options[source.selectedIndex].value);
        source.options[source.selectedIndex].selected = false;

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < arSelected; i++) {

            document.getElementById('<%= destinationSpendingType.ClientID %>').innerHTML =
+ "\n" + document.getElementById('<%= destinationSpendingType.ClientID %>').innerHTML = arSelected[i].value;
        }
    }

         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at the lines marked `//***`

```
function dropValue6(source) {
    var arSelected = [];   // ***
    while (source.selectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if (source.selectedIndex != 0) arSelected.push(source.options[source.selectedIndex].value);
        source.options[source.selectedIndex].selected = false;

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < arSelected.length; i++) {  // ***                
            document.getElementById('<%= destinationSpendingType.ClientID %>').innerHTML = arSelected[i];  // ***
        }
    }    
}
```